# How to get current rewrited URL in Nginx?

Tags: mod-rewrite, nginx, nginx-location

Here is my nginx's configuration file:

```
http {
  index index.html;

  server {
    server_name www.domain1.com;
    access_log logs/domain1.access.log main;

    root /var/www/domain1.com/htdocs;

   rewrite ^(/upload/banner/\d+/).+\.(\d+m?.(jpg|png))$   $1$2 last; 
   # How to get current rewrited URL now? With echo module?
....
....
  }
```

You can see that I have a rewrite in the it.
How to get current rewrited URL now? With echo module?
Could you explain it to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most current URL will be contained in the `$uri` variable.

From the [core module documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_uri):

> $uri
>   current URI in request, normalized
>   The value of $uri may change during request processing, e.g. when doing >internal redirects, or when using index files.